# Python Printing out of Scope ?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this is my program. When the user choose option 1 he should be able to create a Course. After he creates it, he should be able to choose option 3, and display what he entered in option 1. But my problem is that when the course it created, and wants to display it I get this error. ***NameError: name 'myCourse' is not defined ***

```
import Course
import Person
import Student


CREATE = 1
ADD_STUDENTS = 2
COURSE_INFO = 3
ADD_SCORES = 4
QUIT = 5


def main():

    choice = 0

    while choice != QUIT:
        choice = get_menu_choice()

        if choice == CREATE:
            add_Course()
        elif choice == ADD_STUDENTS:
            add_Student()
        elif choice == COURSE_INFO:
            view_Course()
        elif choice == ADD_SCORES:
            add_Scores()
        elif choice == QUIT:
            quit()



def get_menu_choice():
    print()
    print(" Welcome to CourseAware's Faculty Menu")
    print('---------------------------')
    print('1. Create Course ')
    print('2. Add Students to a Course')
    print('3. View Course Information')
    print('4. Add Test scores to a Course')
    print('5. Exit')
    print()

    choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))

    while choice < CREATE or choice > QUIT:
        choice = int(input('Enter a valid choice: '))

    return choice




def add_Course():

    name = input("Enter course name: ")
    number = input("Enter course number: ")
    units = input("Enter courses units: ")
    instructor = input("Enter courses Instructor: ")
    myCourse = Course.Course(name,number,units,instructor)

    print("Courses' Name: ",myCourse.getName())
    print("Courses' Number: ",myCourse.getNumber())
    print("Courses' Units: ",myCourse.getUnits())
    print("Courses' Instructor: ",myCourse.getInstructor())
    print("Course Added!")
    return myCourse

def add_Student():
    Name = input("Enter First and Last Name of Sudent: ")
    Status = input("Enter Status of Stdent: ")
    GPA = input("Enter Students GPA: ")
    newStudent = Student.Student(Name, Status, GPA )

    print("Student' First Name: ",newStudent.getName())
    print("Student' Status: ",newStudent.getStatus())
    print("Student' Instructor: ",newStudent.getGPA())


    infile = open('student.txt','a')
    infile.write('\n')
    infile.write(newStudent)
```

Error is around here

```
def view_Course():



    print("Courses' Name: ",myCourse.getName())
    print("Courses' Number: ",myCourse.getNumber())
    print("Courses' Units: ",myCourse.getUnits())
    print("Courses' Instructor: ",myCourse.getInstructor())

main()
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: myCourse isn't available in this scope. It's inside the function, but defined in a different one. add_Course() returns myCourse, but it isn't saved anywhere.

Comment: How would I save it, so it can be applied everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because `view_Course` function doesn't know about `myCourse` object you have created in `add_Course` function. Though `add_Course` function returns `myCourse` to `main` function, returned `myCourse` value isn't used anywhere in `main`.

You can of course move `myCourse` to global scope level, but it is a bad practice.

It is better to keep `myCourse` at `main` scope level to `view_Course` function as an argument, for example, like this:

```
myCourse = None;
if choice == CREATE:
        myCourse = add_Course(myCourse)
...
elif choice == COURSE_INFO:
        view_Course(myCourse)
```

Comment: I see. Anyway I can fix this, so it be called anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to fix it.

1 way is make `myCourse` global in whole file

```
def view_Course(myCourse):
    global myCourse
```

2 way is transfer variable like this:

```
def view_Course(myCourse):
    print("Courses' Name: ",myCourse.getName())
    print("Courses' Number: ",myCourse.getNumber())
    print("Courses' Units: ",myCourse.getUnits())
    print("Courses' Instructor: ",myCourse.getInstructor())
main()
```

In my opinion second way is better.